# How to calculate between the rows in pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate what percentage of original value my new values are.
What I want to receive is new columns in my Pandas DataFrame.

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
     Feature    Precision   Accuracy    Recall  Specificity F1 score
0   original    0.949367    0.911765    0.9375  0.818182    0.943396
1   new_feat1   0.949367    0.911765    0.9375  0.818182    0.943396
2   new_feat2   0.950617    0.931373    0.9625  0.818182    0.956522
```

And desired outcome would look like this:

```
     Feature    Precision   Accuracy    Recall  Specificity F1 score Precision% Accuracy%   Recall% Specificity%    F1 score%
0   original    0.949367    0.911765    0.9375  0.818182    0.943396 100        100         100     100             100
1   new_feat1   0.949367    0.911765    0.9375  0.818182    0.943396 xxxxxx   xxxxxx       xxxxx    xxxxxx       xxxxxx
2   new_feat2   0.950617    0.931373    0.9625  0.818182    0.956522
```

The calculation so should be like this:

for new_feat1:

- precision% = new_feat1_precision * 100 / original_precision
- accuracy% = new_feat1_accuracy * 100 / original_accuracy
- and so on

Or if it is easier as it was suggested Dataframe can have this format

```
            original    new_feat1   new_feat2
Precision   0.949367    0.950617    0.95122
Accuracy    0.911765    0.931373    0.941176    
Recall      0.9375      0.9625      0.975   
Specificity 0.818182    0.818182    0.818182    
F1 score    0.943396    0.956522    0.962963
```

Then desired output is:

```
            original    new_feat1   new_feat2
Precision   0.949367    0.950617    0.95122
Accuracy    0.911765    0.931373    0.941176    
Recall      0.9375      0.9625      0.975   
Specificity 0.818182    0.818182    0.818182    
F1 score    0.943396    0.956522    0.962963
%Accuracy   100         xxxx        xxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing by the first row with `div` and `iloc[0]`, adding suffix to column names with `add_suffix`, and then joining to the original DataFrame with `join`:

```
df.join(
    df.select_dtypes(float).div(
        df.select_dtypes(float).iloc[0]).add_suffix(' %'))
```

Output:

```
     Feature  Precision  Accuracy  Recall  Specificity  F1_score  Precision %  \
0  original   0.95       0.91      0.94    0.82         0.94      1.0           
1  new_feat1  0.95       0.91      0.94    0.82         0.94      1.0           
2  new_feat2  0.95       0.93      0.96    0.82         0.96      1.0           

   Accuracy %  Recall %  Specificity %  F1_score %  
0  1.00        1.00      1.0            1.00        
1  1.00        1.00      1.0            1.00        
2  1.02        1.03      1.0            1.01
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do is maybe to transpose your dataframe:

```
df1_transposed = df1.T
```

Then, once you did your business as usual, you transpose back if you wish

```
df1 = df1_transposed.T
```